# Modify ACL on newly created window station to deny creation of processes by user in C#

Tags: c#, desktop, acl

We've been tasked on creating a service in C# that creates a separate desktop from the current users desktop. The service will switch back and forth with timed intervals doing different tasks. We've gotten the service to create a new desktop with window station, but one of the tasks is to run the desktop as a different user than the one who created it (and now owns it). We've created a windows user, and the program uses its token to access the desktop.

Now here's the tricky bit. We need to modify the *new* desktops ACL with and ACE that says that the new user is not allowed to create processes on that desktop i.e. a deny all. I've been looking into the reference on MSDN and it seems like the way to go is to get the window stations SACL with *GetSecurityInfo()*, modify it, then set it again with *GetSecurityInfo()*.

However this is as far as I got, and to be perfectly honest I have no clue if it's the right way to go. It just seems right to me. My problems are these:

1. I can't get the methods above working because I'm not able to access the _SE_OBJECT_TYPE and SECURITY_INFORMATION constants/bit flags because I don't understand how you include their respective header-files in c#.
2. How do you modify an ACLs ACE to deny process creation for a single user, which functions do you use?
3. Does anybody know of a simpler and/or smarter way of changing the ACE for the new desktop?